# Oppwa Payments Gateway

Tags: payment, gateway

We're looking to integrate a oppwa payment gateway to our ecommerce but we can't understand the logic of this system.

The question is, Oppwa need a merchant account to able get the payments? Or if not, where go the money?

Any idea about how is working Oppwa?
Thanks,

Comment: You always need a merchant account to configure specifics (like available methods) and retrieve specific data (like your shared secret). What did you try? Which documentation were you provided?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the payment gateway.

On my implementation, the payment gateway company requested some documents for helping me to set up a merchant account. Money is coming directly to my account.